Button does not appear without pressing F5
I'm currently having problems with my code. When I'm logged in as admin, my backoffice button doesn't appear unless I press F5.
useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure window.FB and window.FB.XFBML are defined before calling parse()
    if (window.FB && window.FB.XFBML) {
      window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    } else {
      console.log('Button BackOffice not loaded');
    }
  }, [])

How can I make my button appear immediately after logging in?

You should wait for the FB SDK to complete the login. You can subscribe to Events to wait until is ready. You are going to need something like this:
useEffect(() => {
  // Function to handle the Facebook login event
  const handleFBLogin = (response) => {
    if (window.FB && window.FB.XFBML) {
      window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    } else {
      console.log('Button BackOffice not loaded');
    }
  };

  // Subscribe to the Facebook login event
  if (window.FB) {
    window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', handleFBLogin);
  } else {
    console.log('Facebook SDK not loaded');
  }

  // Clean up the event subscription on component unmount
  return () => {
    if (window.FB) {
      window.FB.Event.unsubscribe('auth.login', handleFBLogin);
    }
  };
}, []);



There's no Facebook event, it's a site I make with my group and when you log in as admin the button doesn't appear unless I update the page.
